# How to create a dynamic piechart out of two dimensional Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, matplotlib, pie-chart

Python 2.7

Need your help with creating a pie chart out of a Numpy array.
Currently every method I try results in no chart being shown.

Numpy array looks like below.

```
array([['A' '506']
 ['B' '80']
 ['C' '6']
 ['...' '15']
 ['Z' '7']],dtype = '|S21')
```

Where number of rows, column values will change.
Number and kind of columns will stay the same.

I tried to:

1. Convert the array to the Pandas data set, apply proper type and create a plt.pie like below. No chart shown.

   ```
   dataset = pd.DataFrame(**array**, columns = ['Description','Metric'])
   dataset[['Metric']] = dataset[['Metric']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

   colors = ["#...", '#...', '#...','#...', '#...', '#...', '#...', '#...', '#...', '#...', '#...'] 

   plt.pie(
   x = dataset['Metric'],
   labels=dataset['Description'],
   shadow=False,
   colors=colors,
   autopct='%1.1f%%',
   )

   plt.axis('equal')

   plt.tight_layout()
   plt.show
   ```
2. Change it to a list, add elements as lists. No chart shown.

   ```
   metrics = list(dataset['Metric'])
   descriptions = list(dataset['Description'])

   plt.pie(
   x = metrics,
   labels=descriptions,
   ... )
   ```

The dataset itself looks good but there seem to be some issues with the dataframe format as the plot cannot be created...

```
>> print dataset
<<
              Description           Metric
0                       A              506
1                       B               80
2                       C                6
3                       D               15
...
8                       X              26
9                       Y               13
10                      Z               7
```

Expected result would be a simple pie chart out of those two columns. It should be created dinamically based on the Metrics value and number of rows.

Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd really recommend storing this data as either a dictionary or a pandas `DataFrame`. In the solution below I convert your data to a dictionary before plotting.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data as given
data = np.array([['A', '506'],
                 ['B', '80'],
                 ['C', '6'],
                 ['...', '15'],
                 ['Z', '7']], dtype = '|S21')

# Create dictionary
data_dict = {}

# Convert byte string to string and string number to int
for row in range(data.shape[0]):
    data_dict[data[row, 0].astype(str)] = int(data[row, 1])

plt.pie(data_dict.values(), labels=data_dict.keys())
```

This gave me the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I have succesfully created a data dictionary however the plot is still not being shown. My data dictionary looks like `{'A': 7, 'B': 6, 'C': 55, 'D': 506, 'E': 13, 'F': 15, 'G': 30, 'H': 75, 'I': 80, 'J': 26, 'K': 26}`. When I try to execute `plt.show()` afterwards, nothing happens. Could you please tell if you have any ideas on what am I doing wrong?